# Cannot iterate over object

Tags: php

I have this object that contains a list of array index:

```
["features"]=>
object(stdClass)#10 (1) {
  ["feature"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(14) "customer_email"
      ["value"]=>
      string(22) "foo@gmail.com"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(18) "license_expiration"
      ["value"]=>
      string(19) "2018-02-25 00:00:00"
    }
  }
}
```

}

I'm trying to iterate in this way:

```
foreach($keyDetails->features as $feature)
       {
         echo $feature;
           //if($feature["subscription_reference"]
       }
```

but the foreach is never fired, why?

Comment: `foreach($keyDetails->features->feature as $feature)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing 2 levels in your foreach. `pkey` first, and `feature` next.

```
foreach ($keyDetails->pkey->features->feature as $feature)
{
     var_dump($feature) ;
}
```

Comment: tried, same, not working don't know why, no error appear and i have enabled it

Comment: @IlRagazzoDiCampagna Please post a `var_dump($keyDetails)` in your question.

Comment: @IlRagazzoDiCampagna It seems missing the object `pkey`, please check the updated anwser.